# Getting the centroid of multiple paths in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, geojson

I'd like to get the total centroid from a selection of multiple geoJson paths.
I know i can get the centroid of a path using [path.centroid](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#path_centroid), but it's not clear to me how ha can get the centroid when i have an array of paths

Answer (score 1):

If you use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33511716/5015356) to calculate a bounding box from a path, you can just append the `d` attributes of the path and calculate the bounding box of them together.

Below I have a map of Saskatchewan in Canada, and I continuously add parts to the selection and recalculate the centroid. You can see this as the labels get longer.

```js
//Width and height
var w = 800;
var h = 800;

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

function getCentroid(element) {
  var bbox = element.getBBox();
  return [bbox.x + bbox.width / 2, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2];
}

//Load in GeoJSON data
d3.json("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5f955d1bbd69750f00c34c5e").then(function(json) {
  // Rewind the features because they are the wrong way around
  json.features = json.features.map(function(feature) {
    return turf.rewind(feature, {
      reverse: true
    });
  }).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.properties.name < a.properties.name;
  });

  var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([w, h], json);

  //Define path generator
  var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

  //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
  svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke", "white");

  var centroids = [];
  var p = "";
  var description = "";
  var tmp = svg.append("path");
  json.features.forEach(function(f, i) {
    p += path(f);
    description += (description ? ", " : "") + f.properties.name;
    tmp.attr("d", p);
    var centroid = getCentroid(tmp.node());
    centroids.push({
      x: centroid[0],
      y: centroid[1],
      description: description
    });
  });
  tmp.remove();

  var centroids = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(centroids)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"
    });

  centroids.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5);

  centroids.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.description;
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
```